# How to extract contents between a specific character in a c string?

Tags: c, parsing

Say I have `char ch[] = "/user/dir1/file.txt";`

I want to use a loop such that:

1st iteration:

```
prints: "user"
```

2nd iteration:

```
prints: "dir1"
```

3rd iteration:

```
prints: "file1.txt"
```

*reach the end of string. Exists the loop*

Comment: What have you tried so far? Questions have to have code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hint: look up `strtok`.

Comment: what about `"///foo///bar///"`? how many loops?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use strtok or its threadsafe version if you are developing a multithreaded program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char ch[] = "/user/dir1/file.txt";
   // Extract the first token
   char * token = strtok(ch, "/");
   // loop through the string to extract all other tokens
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( "%s\n", token ); //printing each token
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It prints **user, dir1/file.txt**. It has to print **user, dir1, file.txt.** OR if the char is "/user/dir1/subdir2/file.txt, it has to print **user, dir1, subdir2, file.txt**

Comment: I found the solution. `token = strtok(NULL, " ");` to token = `strtok(NULL, "/");`

Answer (score 0):

A "simple", portable, thread-safe solution that does *not* modify the string, as the approach using `strtok()` does. So the approach below can be applied to literals as well!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  const char * s = "/user/dir1/file.txt";

  for (const char * ps = s, *pe;
    pe = strchr(ps, '/'), ps != pe ?printf("%.*s\n", (int) (pe - ps), ps) :0, pe;
    ps = pe + 1);
}
```

The only limitation this code is facing, is that the tokens within the string to be parsed may not be longer then `INT_MAX` characters.